# Can not get Twitter trends for Iran

Tags: python, twitter

I'd like to get Twitter trends for Iran from twitter-api using python and [this](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter) twitter package:

```
import twitter

#WOE_ID Obtained from http://woeid.rosselliot.co.nz/lookup/iran
IR_WOE_ID = 23424851

auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

print twitter_api

ir_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=IR_WOE_ID)

print ir_trends
```

In response I get

```
twitter.api.TwitterHTTPError: Twitter sent status 404 for URL: 1.1/trends/place.json using parameters: (id=2251945&oauth_consumer_key=***&oauth_nonce=***&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1530506965&oauth_token=***&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=***)
details: {u'errors': [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist.', u'code': 34}]}
```

I don't get any error for other WOE_ID country codes like for`India` and the `US`.

What could be wrong here? How can I fix this?

Comment: From the link you posted, `WOE_ID` for Iran appears to be `23424851`

Comment: Sorry, I modified the value. but I still get error for `23424851`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Twitter]Twitter doesn't seem to have anything trending for Iran.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Twitter is completely blocked in Iran.

Comment: Twitter is blocked in Iran. But does that mean that twitter has removed Iran from its trend locations?

Comment: I assume that that's part of the censorship package.

Answer (score -1):

Twitter did not have anything trending for Iran also some online tools did not have Iran in their list [TwitterTrends.info](https://twittertrends.info) [trends24.in](https://trends24.in)... seems like twitter completely banned Iran